# NextJS how to send client logs when error occurs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

We have a static rendering for NextJS and occasionally some users receive `Application error: a client-side exception has occurred` which is the catch-all page for a fatal error using NextJS. I couldn't find how how to catch these errors and send them somewhere so they can be debugged. I did see something about an `_error` page but this is actually the 404 page. Any insights on how to catch the client-side fatal errors and log them somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a service such as Sentry to monitor these errors.

See docs:

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/error-handling#reporting-errors
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-sentry

Comment: I never actually came across that Error boundary thing, idk how i missed that. thank you! I'll dig into this